# Copying conditional Formatting in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I use conditional formatting to format a cell depending on the values of another cell. This is the rule:

> Cell Value not between `=$BV$10*0,5` and `=$BV$10*0,5`

This rule is saved on Cell Y10

(Explanation: If the Value in Y10 is inbetween 0,5...1,5 * BV10 apply the formatting)

I want to use this rule on many different Cells but the formula should adjust automaticly, just like in a "normal" formula.

When I copy the format using the Format Painter the formula is copied without any changes. But I need the row to be changed. For example, when copying to Y11 the formula should be changed to :

```
 =$BV$11*0,5
```

Is there any way to achieve this or to change `$BV$10` into `$[this column+83]$[this row]` or something like that?

Comment: Can you not do a format painter?

Comment: A reason for downvote would be helpful. (Especially because at least one guy was able to solve my problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. `$` is used to lock the cell reference.
So to get what you need just change your formula to this unlocking the rows:

`=$BV10*0,5 and =$BV10*1` ~~> I change the limits to actually test the formula

So if you want your column to move as well, then remove the other `$` sign.
Also, you can explicitly apply this formatting to other cells by supplying the range in `Applies To` argument like below:

[image: format dialogue]

Take note that you can actually put the formatting in any cell.
But the effect will always be on the Range you explicitly define in `Applies to`.
I discourage using the `Copy Paste Format` as this sometimes overlaps formattings you've done.
To apply the formatting to a group of different range, just separate the ranges with a `,` comma like what you see below:

[image: multi range]

So the formatting will then be applied to `$Z$10:$Z$20` as well.
It is the same as `$Y$10:$Z$20`, but I just want to point out that it can be used to none contingous range.
And since your column is locked with your formatting, it will still be references to `$BV(x)` where x is the corresponding row in Y and Z.

Comment: Awesome response. Honestly I expected a "this is not possible" answer :)