# Macro for removing conditional formatting fill color Red

Tags: vba, excel

I have a large excel report and I am trying to make life easier for my technicians.

I have cells where if a number is not within 10% of another cell then that cell will highlight in RED.  My problem is I do NOT want my customers to see the red highlight in my report.  I have to convert my excel reports to PDF.

Is there a Macro code that would only take out the conditional formatting for highlight RED?
I have other conditional formatting in my report and that's why I cannot use the Macro code that deletes all conditional formatting.

Also, is there a Macro code that will make it go back to RED?

Any help on this is appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes. First you need to identify the range you're working on.
Then check if your range has formatting, delete if yes, apply otherwise (like a toggling).
Below code does just that. Change the lines I've commented and adapt. HTH.

```
Sub ColorUnColor()
    Dim myformat As String
    Dim cfr As Range

    myformat = "=A1<(0.1*B1)" '~~> change to suit

    With Sheet2 '~~> change to suit
        Set cfr = .Range("D1:D10") '~~> change to suit
        If cfr.FormatConditions.Count = 0 Then
            .Range("A1").FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, , myformat
            With .Range("A1").FormatConditions(1)
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                .ModifyAppliesToRange cfr
            End With
        Else
            cfr.FormatConditions.Delete
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Important:** You can assign conditional formatting in any Range, but it will be applied to what you set in *ModifyAppliedToRange* which I discussed in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23295082/copying-conditional-formatting-in-excel).

Answer (score 0):

You could use this to clear any cell on the sheet that is colored red (255).  Not sure if that's exactly what you need.

```
Sub testes()

Dim SrchRng As Range
Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    For Each Source In SrchRng
        If Source.Interior.Color = 255 Then
            Source.Interior.Color = xlNone
        End If
    Next Source

End Sub
```

As for going back to red couldn't you just run the macro you already have?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Selection.FormatConditions.Delete
```